# what is the difference between partials in ruby on rails to React?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, partials

As I understood, React helps you reuse html components, which i can also do with partials.

What is the difference between them and what more can i do with react that i cannot do with partials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are solving similar problem (separating shared page elements for reuse), but they are doing it on different "levels". Also, with React, it is not the only problem it is trying to solve. If you watch F8 conference recordings about reasons why Facebook decided to create React.js, you will learn that one of the main reasons was to guarantee one directional flow of data. This resulted in components that don't have "surprise" behaviour and the code is more maintainable. Also, React can bind your models to UI elements and much more. Not taking into account that React is for client end and RoR backend partial management.

Anyhow, as you can see, even though React does share one functionality with RoR partials, it is much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

React not just helps you to reuse your html, but the main purpose is to move your front end logic of your application from server side to user side and make easy to maintain it. This is reduces complexity of your application especially in front end heavy applications.

If you would like to create a single page applications using rails partials, then you have to write a lot of JS code in order to change content, changing all the components of the page and make everything looks smoothly. For complex front end code you need to carefully structure and design your code, and React is kind of structure or behaviour for your code, especially when you are using with FLUX design pattern.